# Oracle SQL query result into a temporary table for use in a sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, temp-tables

I want to create a temporary table which is inturn derived from a query to be used in another sub-query so as to simplify the rownum() and partition by condition. The query I have entered is as below but it returns an error t.trlr_num invalid identifier.

```
with t as
(select distinct
          ym.trlr_num,
           ym.arrdte,
           ri.invnum,
           ri.supnum
from rcvinv ri, yms_ymr ym
where ym.trlr_cod='RCV'
and ri.trknum = ym.trlr_num
and ym.wh_id <=50
and ym.trlr_stat in ('C','CI','R','OR')
and ym.arrdte is not null
order by ym.arrdte desc
)
select trlr_number, invnum, supnum
from
(
  select 
    t.trlr_num, t.invnum, t.supnum,
    row_number() over (partition by t.trlr_number,t.invnum order by t.arrdte) as rn 
  from t
)
where rn = 1;
```

From above, I put a condition to create a table t as a temporary table to be used in the below select statement. But is seems to error out with invalid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

seems typo, replace trlr_number with trlr_num and it work

```
with t as
(select distinct
          ym.trlr_num,
           ym.arrdte,
           ri.invnum,
           ri.supnum
from rcvinv ri, yms_ymr ym
where ym.trlr_cod='RCV'
and ri.trknum = ym.trlr_num
and ym.wh_id <=50
and ym.trlr_stat in ('C','CI','R','OR')
and ym.arrdte is not null
order by ym.arrdte desc
)
select trlr_num, invnum, supnum
from
(
  select 
    t.trlr_num, t.invnum, t.supnum,
    row_number() over (partition by t.trlr_num,t.invnum order by t.arrdte) as rn 
  from t
)
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **multiple subqueries** in the **WITH clause** as separate temporary tables. It would be nice and easy to understand:

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT ym.trlr_num trlr_num,
    ym.arrdte arrdte,
    ri.invnum invnum,
    ri.supnum supnum
  FROM rcvinv ri,
    yms_ymr ym
  WHERE ym.trlr_cod ='RCV'
  AND ri.trknum     = ym.trlr_num
  AND ym.wh_id     <=50
  AND ym.trlr_stat IN ('C','CI','R','OR')
  AND ym.arrdte    IS NOT NULL
  ),
  t1 AS (
  SELECT t.trlr_num,
  t.arrdte,
  t.invnum,
  t.supnum,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t.trlr_num, t.invnum ORDER BY t.trlr_num, t.invnum DESC) rn
  FROM t
  )
SELECT trlr_num, arrdte, invnum, supnum 
   FROM t1 
  WHERE rn = 1;
```